# recuperar los datos del usuario logueado - Laravel auth

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla emprendimientos con usuario_id, necesito que se recuperen en una tabla los emprendimientos del usuario logueado.
En el controlador de emprendimiento

escribi la siguiente funcion

````
   {
       $usuarioid = auth()->user()->id;
   $emprendimientos = Emprendimiento::where('usuario_id', $usuarioid);
   return view('emprendimiento.index')->with('emprendimientos',$emprendimientos);
       
   }``` 

No me recupera datos.

si dejo asi la funcion index

 public function index()
 ```  {
       
       $emprendimientos = Emprendimiento::all();
       return view('emprendimiento.index')->with('emprendimientos',$emprendimientos);
   }``` 

Se recuperan todos los emprendimientos sin filtrar por el usuario logueado
````

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor muestra tu modelo Emprendimiento y el modolo User, debes relacionar los dos modelos y ya es más fácil solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Entre user y emprendimientos ¿qué tipo de relación existe?

Answer (score 1):

Relaciona tus modelos agregando estas fuciones:

Modelo User:

```php
public function emprendimientos() {
   return $this->hasMany(Emprendimiento::class);
}
```

Modelo Emprendimiento:

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Ahora en el controlador solo haces lo siguiente:

```php
public function index(){
   $authUser = auth()->user();
   $empredimientos = $authUser->emprendimientos;
   return view('empredimientos', compact($emprendimientos));
}
```